# Using global variable in function

Tags: r, global-variables

I have a very big dataset and I analyze it with R.

The problem is that I want to add some columns with different treatments on my dataset AND I need some recursive function which use some global variable. Each function modify some global variable et create some variables. So the duplication of my dataset in memory is a big problem...

I read some documentation: if I didn't misunderstand, neither the use of `<<-` nor `assign()` could help me...

What I want:

```
mydata <- list(read.table(), ...)
myfunction <- function(var1, var2) {
   #modification of global mydata
   mydata = ...
   #definition of another variable with the new mydata
   var3 <- ...
   #recursive function
   mydata = myfunction(var2, var3)
}
```

Do you have some suggestions for my problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `<<-` and `assign` will work:

```
myfunction <- function(var1, var2) {
   # Modification of global mydata
   mydata <<- ...
   # Alternatively:
   #assign('mydata', ..., globalenv())

   # Assign locally as well
   mydata <- mydata

   # Definition of another variable with the new mydata
   var3 <- ...

   # Recursive function
   mydata = myfunction(var2, var3)
}
```

That said, it’s almost always a bad idea to want to modify global data from a function, and there’s almost certainly a more elegant solution to this.

Furthermore, note that `<<-` is actually not the same as assigning to a variable in `globalenv()`, rather, it assigns to a variable in the *parent scope*, whatever that may be. For functions defined in the global environment, it’s the global environment. For functions defined elsewhere, it’s *not* the global environment.

Comment: I knew that, but when I coded it: assign() or <<- I modified mydata in the global environment but not in the local environment of my function. So when I used the recursive function in myfunction() : the modifications were not apply.
The modifications are like : dataset[dataset[, "colx"]==var1, ] = anotherfunction() so assign() is not really handy here for me...

Comment: @EaudeRoche Oh, got it. But actually the solution to this is straightforward: do two assigns, one local and one nonlocal. See my edit. You can also change the order of these operations around: assign *first* locally and then globally.

Comment: @konrad-rudolf OK ! So I will have to duplicate the dataset for each iteration anyway.